# Get lists of coordinates from OpenCV contours in Python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am looking for a way to retrieve lists of coordinates from contours generated by OpenCV.

For example, if I have an OpenCV contour:

```
cnt = [[[272 271]] 
       [[271 272]]
       [[270 272]]
       [[269 272]]
       [[268 272]]]
```

How to create list of contours x coordinates:

```
x = [273, 271, 270, 269, 268]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
cnt = []
cnt.append([[272, 271]])
cnt.append([[271, 272]])
cnt.append([[270, 272]])
cnt.append([[269, 272]])
cnt.append([[268, 272]])
```

Then, to get a list with the X values, you could use:

```
xList = [x[0][0] for x in cnt] # --> [272, 271, 270, 269, 268]
```

See this working here: http://ideone.com/gWnhQ5

Comment: Thansk a lot! That's it!

Answer (score 1):

From the OpenCV documentation:

> contours is a Python list of all the contours in the image. Each
>   individual contour is a Numpy array of (x,y) coordinates ...

So you can access just the x-coordinates with:

```
contour[:,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it using below code:

```
x_waypoints = (x_y_array.flatten(1)[:length_of_contours2])
y_waypoints = (x_y_array.flatten(1)[length_of_contours2:])
```

You can print the result of `flatten(1)`, and have a check.